# GWT production mode doesn't work on Chrome browser

Tags: gwt, google-chrome, production

I compiled my GWT application and am testing it in the production mode. The application works fine on all browsers, except Google Chrome, which only an empty page shows up.

I tried to see if there were any options for compilation, but there weren't. Can somebody let me know what's wrong?

thanks,

--
Javad

Comment: The problem only exist when I want to run the application itself(i.e running the generated code) directly in Chrome. When I embedded the js files in another page, Chrome works as well.

Comment: which version of GWT? which versio of Chrome?
How do you compile?

Comment: Ittai, sorry for responding with delay:
GWT 2.0.4
Chrome 5.0.375.127

I'm using Eclipse plugin for compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you test via URL like 'file:///' , Chrome will block this URL
The solution is upload your file to server (or localhost)
and test via 'http://'

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the answer by user453586.
To run it from local host do the following:

1. Run the project in eclipse(run as->web app)
2. Take the generated localhost url and remove the gwt.codeserv part, e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8888/StockWatcher.html`

This will run it in production mode, you would notice the increase in speed of the page load.